# Google App Engine Send Mail not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm having a problem with sending an email through Google App Engine with Python. I have a website running on a different host which contains a form posting to a Python script in GAE. The script works fine, but fails if I add the "send mail" function in my Python script. I've added:

```
    self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
```

But I still get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.summit-tech-help.appspot.com/. Origin http://summittechhelp.x10.mx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here's my Python script.

```
import cgi,webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail

class ProblemRedirect(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
        problem_text = (cgi.escape(self.request.get('problem_text')))
        student_name =(cgi.escape(self.request.get('student_name')))
        student_email =(cgi.escape(self.request.get('student_email')))
        sender_address= "Summit Tech Help <techhelpsummit@gmail.com>"
        subject = "New Support Ticket!"
        body= "test."
        mail.send_mail(sender_address,sender_address,subject,body)




application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', ProblemRedirect),
], debug=True)
```

The commented line is what is causing the error. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

I also tried adding:

```
http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

to my app.yaml file, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error parsing yaml file:
Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.
  in "/Users/ajay/summit-tech-help/app.yaml", line 13, column 1
```

Comment: Are you posting to this page via javascript? Is techhelpsummit@gmail.com an admin on your apppengine site(it needs to be if you want to send mail from that account). You should also be returning something from this method.

Comment: @RobCurtis, yes I'm sending it from the admin account. How do I return something? Does that affect the rest of the code?

Comment: The return doesn't matter. I think it'll return status 200 anyway. However, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: are you loading the correct path? The URL http://www.summit-tech-help.appspot.com/ is 404 not found while I attempted to check for the headers returned

Comment: Sorry, I disabled it temporarily. I'm using `http://s-t-h-c.appspot.com/`. I'm simply linking my form to this, is that how it is supposed to work? The script is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the line:

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
```

Directly in code, not in the app.yaml.